# HQL Associated Object NOT Exists

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, hql

I've seen a couple pages that come close to this, but I'm looking for a simpler answer.

I have an object `FinancialStatementLine` that *can* reference a `Payment` entity. I want to use HQL to find the `FinancialStatementLine` entities that match certain criteria but do **not** have an associated `Payment` object.  My HQL statement looks like this:

```
var query = _Session.CreateQuery(
    @"select lines from FinancialStatementLine lines
        inner join fetch lines.Statement statement  
        where statement.FinancialStatementId := statementId
        and lines.Payment is null
        and length(lines.CheckNumber) > 0")
    .SetParameter("statementId", financialStatementId);
```

It seems that would be the answer, but I'm getting a `NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException` (Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException) and the only thing I can imagine that I'm doing wrong is trying to use the `is null` clause on an associated entity instead of a property.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you have a syntax error in your HQL?

```
where statement.FinancialStatementId := statementId
```

should actually be:

```
where statement.FinancialStatementId = :statementId
```